# how to let a textfield back to initial status

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how to let a textfiled back to initial status.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C1Zo.png)

step 1 :
when i choice the 'Others ' and give a value to the textfield .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xihv0.png)

step 2:
now i change 'Others' to '3KG' option.   I hope the textfield back to initial status .

with the code as follow , just empty the value,but the title not back to initial position. ...

```
const handleWeightChange = (event) => {
    if(event.target.value === 'a4') {
        totalWeightRef.current.focus();
    }
    else {
        totalWeightRef.current.value = null;
    }
};

        <RadioGroup row  aria-label="type" name="name" className={classes.weightradio} onChange={handleWeightChange}> 
                    <FormControlLabel value="a1"  control={<Radio />} label="1KG" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="a2"  control={<Radio />} label="2KG" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="a3"  control={<Radio />} label="3KG" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="a4"  control={<Radio />} label="Others" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextField id="totalWeight" label="重量KG" inputRef={totalWeightRef} />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Btm.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Comment: yes , have done .

Comment: Hey there, you'll need to post all the relevant code... it looks like there is much more going on in that file. Where is the `inputRef` on the TextField defined and managed, for instance?

The examples in the Material UI demos all manage themselves visually as you add or remove the value, play with them here:
[Material UI TextField API](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) 
Please note the `TextField` component has a `value` parameter - most likely you'll just want to set this back to an empty string `""` and that should fix your problem